# InstantClick.io & Datatables jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, pjax

So I found out about InstantClick, tested it and got it working on a couple pages in our backend but it is falling apart when it needs to execute anything datatables related. jQuery Datatables to be exact. I wanted to know if anyone has any idea on how to fix this problem, and if there isn't a way how can I avoid these pages from being loaded using PJAX? I really want the system to be universal but I have a feeling that I am taking a shot in the dark here, as I cannot recreate a Datatable nor destroy it simultaneously with the page. As a matter of fact, anything PHP related does not seem to pull well, is there a work around for these issues or do I have to suck it up and not use it at all?

Thanks for the help, sorry I don't have any code to show, as I am just asking a question related to the library itself.

UPDATE!

Still need help but I am getting closer, it is redrawing the table but not changing the data per page. Here is what I am doing:

```
InstantClick.init();
$(document).ready(function(){
  // table.fnDestroy();
  table.fnDraw();
  table.fnReloadAjax(ajaxSession2);
});
```

The table variable is the table variable that is shared on both pages. If someone has a work around to avoid this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to work with Javascript and dataTables, you will want to put your functions that interact with table data in `fnDrawCallback()` (see [callbacks](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks)). This will make sure the Javascript is run after each dataTable "draw." Your php will be run before the dataTable is drawn most likely though. I recommend using Javascript if you are trying to manipulate data after the page loads.

Example:

```
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "aTargets":  [ "no-sort" ]
                }
            ],
            "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                $('.some-button').click(function() {
                    // do something
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is what InstantClick.io is handling, the problem is that it won't redraw the table when it is PJAX'd into the page itself. So the question is how can I redraw the table or do anything by that matter because it seems all of my JS is broken.

Comment: `fnDraw()` will redraw to the table

Comment: I'll give it a shot, it's just acting weird and I really want to use this feature but I feel the dynamic Ajax and PHP calls I'm making are going to be messed up, thanks for the idea though!